# Is it bad to post drafts answers?

Tags: support, answers

I am considering to post a draft answer AKA "*my advance*" (obviously warning to the users that it is incomplete and future updates are coming) on [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/score-a-cribbage-hand)

I think my 90% done answer can help people by borrowing some of my ideas.

But I am unsure if posting drafts answers is unwanted.

So what do you advice me, to post or not to post this advance?:

```js
    //JavaScript
    str="AD 2D 3D 4D | 2D".split(/\s\|\s|\s/);
    i=j=v=f=p=0;
    arr=[];arr2=[];//don't merge arr=arr2=[]

    for(sc="SCDH";i<5;i++){
        x=str[i];
        xx=x[0];

        arr[sc.indexOf(x[1])]+=".";
        arr2[("ATJQK".indexOf(xx)+1)||(xx- -4)]+=".";

        if((i<4)&&(x==("J"+sc[sc.indexOf(str[4][1])]))){
            j++;
        }

        v+=((xx=="A")?1:((xx*1)||10));
    }

    y=(yy=(arr+"")).indexOf("....");//cache yy counterproductive?
    f=(!!(++y))?(yy[y+3]==".")?5:(str.length<6)?4:0:0;//improve !!()?

    for(i in arr2){
        p+=(((xxx=((arr2[i]+"").length-9))*(xxx-1))/2);
    }



    //Fifteens: for each subset of five cards whose sum is 15, add two points.
    //if(v==15) add +2

    //Pairs: for each pair of cards with the same rank (not value), add two points.
    //add +(p*2)

    //Runs: for each maximal run of consecutive cards of length longer than 2, add the length of the run in points.
    //

    //Flush: if all five cards are the same suit, add five points. Otherwise, if all but the up card are the same suit, add four points. If this is a crib hand, the four-point variant is not counted.
    //add +f

    //Nobs: if there is a jack in hand with the same suit of the up card, add one point.
    //if(j) add +1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it's useful to post your own answer, even if not golfed, as a proof of feasibility. For example, [Generate Newton fractals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/generate-newton-fractals/) generated some discussion in the comments as to whether it was golfable, and that's the kind of situation in which the question setter could intervene with "I have a working solution in XYZ chars, and I'll post it in a week".

In the case of your cribbage question, there's nothing difficult about the problem. So while you can by all means answer it yourself (with a golfed solution), it's not really worth cluttering up the page with a non-golfed solution which serves purely as a proof of feasibility. As a tactical matter (in terms of keeping the question on the front page without upsetting people), I'd wait until a week after posting it before posting your own answer.

Comment: great advise, I will follow your advise

Comment: Good answer. I like to see proof of feasibility answers on on question that look really challenging, but it doesn't see necessary here.